# keypad popup blocks view of application in delphi xe5 Firemonkey

Tags: android, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I am using firemonkey to develop an android application. When selecting an edit the keypad pops up.

My problem is, This keypad blocks the view of the edit. So you cannot see what you type.

The screen also cannot scroll up above the keypad in this event, how can i enable the screen to scroll up when the keypad is in view?

Answer (score 2):

You have to move the edit yourself to proper position when the keyboard pops up. There are two events of form you can use: FormVirtualKeyboardShown and FormVirtualKeyboardHidden.
Code example is available here:
http://www.fmxexpress.com/keep-controls-visible-when-virtual-keyboard-pops-up-in-firemonkey-on-android-and-ios/